# Weighted mean across several matrices - element by element

Tags: r, matrix, mean, weighted

I have 'mylist" - a list of same size matrices:

```
mylist <- vector("list", 5) 
set.seed(123)
for(i in 1:5){
  mylist[[i]] <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow = 3)
}
```

I also have a vector of weights 'mywgts' - same length as 'mylist'

```
mywgts <- c(0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2)
```

I need to calculate a weighted mean of these matrices - element by element.
The result will be a 3 by 3 matrix where the first element is:

```
mylist[[1]][1,1]*mywgts[1] + mylist[[2]][1,1]*mywgts[2] + 
mylist[[3]][1,1]*mywgts[3] + mylist[[4]][1,1]*mywgts[4] + 
mylist[[5]][1,1]*mywgts[5]
```

I know how to do it by looping through all elements of a matrix. But I am looking for a more parsimonious/elegant R-like solution.
Also - the actual length of 'mylist' is not known in advance.

Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 5):

You may try

```
 res <- Reduce(`+`,Map(`*`, mylist, mywgts))
 res
 #         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
 #[1,]  0.6852912  0.2116715 0.7993867
 #[2,] -0.8815045 -1.9811868 1.2558095
 #[3,]  1.5150166  0.8780412 0.7254080
```

`Map` is a wrapper for `mapply`, which is a multivariate version of `sapply`.  The function (`*`) is applied to the corresponding elements of first ('mylist') and second elements ('mywgts'), and then use `Reduce` to sum the corresponding elements of the `list`.

If you need the `mean`, divide by the length of 'mylist`.

```
  res/length(mylist)
```

Using the OP's calculation

```
mylist[[1]][1,1]*mywgts[1] + mylist[[2]][1,1]*mywgts[2] + 
mylist[[3]][1,1]*mywgts[3] + mylist[[4]][1,1]*mywgts[4] + 
mylist[[5]][1,1]*mywgts[5]
#[1] 0.6852912

mylist[[1]][1,2]*mywgts[1] + mylist[[2]][1,2]*mywgts[2] + 
mylist[[3]][1,2]*mywgts[3] + mylist[[4]][1,2]*mywgts[4] + 
mylist[[5]][1,2]*mywgts[5]
#[1] 0.2116715
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much - this is exactly the type of solution I was looking for!